# How to pass array to graphql mutation using axios

Tags: axios, graphql

I have created a mutation that accepts an array of objects. I tested it with an apollo client and it's working fine in my apollo client query is looks like this.

```
mutation {
  createStudent(createStudentInput: [{
    name:"Jhone Doe"
    email:"Jhonedoe@gamil.com"
    dob:"1996-01-21"
  },
  {
    name:"Jhone Doe1"
    email:"Jhonedoe1@scl.com"
    dob:"2000-01-22"
  }
  ]) {
    id,
    name
    dob
  }
}
```

But when I try to perform the mutation using Axios it's throwing an error `Request failed with status code 400`.this is the qraphql query I'm passing to the Axios. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Please note that `records` is an array of objects

```
const graphqlQuery = {
      query: `
      mutation {
            createStudent(createStudentInput:${records}) {
              id,
              name
              dob
            }
          }`,
      variables: {
      },
    };
```

My Axios request

```
  try {
      const results = await axios({
        url: endpoint,
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        data: graphqlQuery,
      });
      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error occured:${error}`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well for one thing you aren't even `JSON.stringify`ing `records`, second you should probably use the `variables` section to add that since that's the point of the `variables` section

Comment: I did stringify the records but it didn't work.do I need to stringify each and every object inside the array or stringify the whole array at once?. another thing is I cant figure out how to use variables here.